# How to how to nest a method inside config/initializers/content_security_policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I wanna set content_security_policy in my rails app. To do this I uncommented Rails.application.config.content_security_policy in content_security_policy.rb but in `policy.connect_src :self` I wanna pass a different values depends on environment. I create a method but I don't know how to call it inside this file since it's not a class.

`content_security_policy.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.connect_src :self, "#{sources}", :ws, :wss
  policy.font_src    :self
  policy.img_src     :self
  policy.object_src  :none
  policy.script_src  :self
  policy.style_src   :self, :unsafe_inline
  # Specify URI for violation reports
  # policy.report_uri "/csp-violation-report-endpoint"
end

def sources
  case Rails.env
  when 'test'
    'localhost:*/'
  when 'development'
    'localhost:*/'
  when 'staging'
    '*.somepath.co:*/'
  else
    '*.somepath.com:*/ *.somepath.com:*/'
  end
end
```

with code above I've got an error:

> undefined local variable or method `self_sources' for main:Object (NameError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling method `sources` before it is defined. This is why you receive `NameError`.

Please, put its definition at the beginning of `content_security_policy.rb`.

```rb
def sources
  case Rails.env
  when 'test'
    'localhost:*/'
  when 'development'
    'localhost:*/'
  when 'staging'
    '*.somepath.co:*/'
  else
    '*.somepath.com:*/ *.somepath.com:*/'
  end
end

Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.connect_src :self, "#{sources}", :ws, :wss
  policy.font_src    :self
  policy.img_src     :self
  policy.object_src  :none
  policy.script_src  :self
  policy.style_src   :self, :unsafe_inline
  # Specify URI for violation reports
  # policy.report_uri "/csp-violation-report-endpoint"
end
```

And everything should work.

Also, in general, it is not a good idea to define methods inside initializer files, until you really need it, because those methods will be available almost in any place of your app as just `sources`.

So, probably the best solution will be the following:

```rb
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  sources =
    case Rails.env
    when 'test'
      'localhost:*/'
    when 'development'
      'localhost:*/'
    when 'staging'
      '*.somepath.co:*/'
    else
      '*.somepath.com:*/ *.somepath.com:*/'
    end

  policy.connect_src :self, "#{sources}", :ws, :wss
  policy.font_src    :self
  policy.img_src     :self
  policy.object_src  :none
  policy.script_src  :self
  policy.style_src   :self, :unsafe_inline
  # Specify URI for violation reports
  # policy.report_uri "/csp-violation-report-endpoint"
end
```

or

```rb
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.connect_src :self, "#{ContentSecurityPolicy.sources}", :ws, :wss
  policy.font_src    :self
  policy.img_src     :self
  policy.object_src  :none
  policy.script_src  :self
  policy.style_src   :self, :unsafe_inline
  # Specify URI for violation reports
  # policy.report_uri "/csp-violation-report-endpoint"
end
```

where `ContentSecurityPolicy.sources` is defined somewhere else in your app.

Thanks for your attention.